# Protractor --grep more than one pattern

Tags: protractor

I have protractor tests set up and I would like to use the --grep command to run more than one test. For example, i have 4 tests **in different spec files** named:

Create Account

Login

Logout

Remove Session

I would like to use the --grep command to only run tests "Login" and "Logout", without having to use FIT.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `suites` in your config.  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L254

Comment: Using suites mean that I already know the name of the test and the Spec file it's in. --grep on the other hands reads the specs that you sent and tries to find that text inside as a test. Right?

Answer (score 0):

`--grep` option has support for [extended regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) so you can run command:

```
protractor --grep "Login|Logout"
```

If you want to be more strict with test names and suite name you can use ^ and $ with `--grep` option, but you must know: suite name and test name is concatenated with space. So to run specific tests from different suites run command as:

```
protractor --grep "^Suite name1 Login$|^Suite name2 Logout$"
```